# How to send notification when there is a data change in firebase in Unity?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification

I have been googling this for a while but I couldn't get any closer. I'm developing a 2d mobile game in unity and I use Firebase database. What I want to do is a simple friend request system. Assume that there are users A and B. Also, there is a Users node in Firebase realtime database. When user A adds user B as a friend, id of user A is being written in FriendRequests node of User B. Then there should be a notification sent to User B even if the game is not running.

In short, I want to send notification when there is a data change in Firebase real time database in Unity even if the app is closed. How can I achieve that? Thank you in advance for any idea.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a Firebase Cloud Function, which is backend code that you get to execute on Firebase servers.

There, you need to create a [realtime database trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events). You probably need an `onWrite` on `FriendRequests`. That trigger will execute every time there is a change there. In it, you will use Firebase Admin SDK to initiate the notification.

To send the notification, you need the FCM keys of the user. You usually get it in the client and make it save it in the database. There can be more than one FCM per user as they can log in on multiple devices. The cloud function usually sends the same notification to all FCM keys of the user.